# PowerBI- How to increment a column for an hourly basis?

Tags: powerbi, dax

So, I have a table with many columns and what I am trying to do is increment the number of sales that have been in that hour and then reset it after after the next hour. I have tried to use summarize key word, but it doesn't seem to be letting me accumulate it. At the moment my data is in 15min bands so the data shows sales in that 15 minute time period. But I would like to accumulate it into next hour.

This is what I have now

```
15minperiod.    Sales
09:00:00.        10
09:15:00.        10
09:30:00.        10
09:45:00.        10
10:00:00.        10
10:15:00.        9
10:20:00.        13
```

This is what I would like to get:

```
15minperiod.       Sales          Sales in hour
    09:00:00.        10.              10
    09:15:00.        10               20
    09:30:00.        10               30
    09:45:00.        10               40
    10:00:00.        10               10
    10:15:00.        9                19
    10:20:00.        13               32
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this can be done with a calculated column like this:

```
Sales in an hour = 
var currentTime = [15minperiod]

return
CALCULATE(
    SUM('Data'[Sales]);
    FILTER(
        ALL('Data');
        'Data'[15minperiod] <= currentTime && HOUR('Data'[15minperiod]) = HOUR(currentTime)
    )
)
```